# Adding every second column in a matrix starting from the 3rd column in r

Tags: r

I would like to add the values of each row for every second column in a matrix of the following form:

```
1  1  100 2 104 4 200
2  1  100 2 103 3 203
3  1  100 3 101 3 304
4  1  100 4 105 2 201
```

Here I would like to add the 3rd column and then every second one, producing the following output:

```
404
406
505
406
```

Can this be done without a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is named `df`.

```
 apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x[seq(3,length(x),2)]))
[1] 404 406 505 406
```

Comment: yes that's easy for only 7 columns, but what if I would like to use it for matrices with varying lengths?

Comment: @user1723765 updated solution to work with different column number

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
rowSums(df[,-c(1,2)][, c(TRUE, FALSE)])
# [1] 404 406 505 406
```

where `[, -c(1,2)]` discards the first two columns and `[, c(TRUE, FALSE)]` keeps every other column.

Answer (score 2):

```
rowSums(df[,seq(from=3, to=ncol(df), by=2)])
```